# How can i rebuild my Info.plist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, objective-c-2.0, xcode4.3

I added a "Location" (App registers for location updates) to the "Required background modes" and after i deleted it from the Info.plist but the App still has the same Info.plist even deleted. How can i refresh my Info.plist the new parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Delete and reinstall the app on your device. That will refresh everything.

Comment: @ZiadTamim Try cleaning your build (command + shift + K) or even delete it. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

First double check the info.plist file, make sure it actually got saved... Then....

Delete the app from your device, clean your build (Shift + Command + K), then run (Command + R) it again. If not, try quiting Xcode then running again.